# How to find minimum value of this implicit function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

It is difficult for me to calculate this, what is the minimum $a$ such that
$2|~x-y~|\leq a|~2x-3y^2-3~|$ holds for all $x,y\in R$ with $|~x~|<y$. equivalent to what maximum of $\frac {2|~x-y~|}{3|~2x-3y^2-3~|}$.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x$ is $3$ and $y$ is $1$, there's no such number $a$. (Or at least that was a counterexample until you added the condition that $|x| < y$, which effectively says that $y$ isn't an arbitrary real, but rather that $y \ge 0$).

**Post-comment additions**

That constrains you to the region $-y < x < y$. If you let $t = x + y$, then you have
$$
0 \le y \\
0 < t < 2y
$$
and your equation becomes
$$
2|t - 2y| \le a | 2(t - y) - 3 y^2 - 3|
$$
Now since $t - 2y < 0$, by the second constraint, this can be rewritten
$$
2(2y - t) \le a | 2(t - y) - 3 y^2 - 3|
$$

Now I claim that the expression inside the remaining absolute values is also always negative.

That expression in absolute values consists of a negative number, namely $-3(1 + y^2)$, added to $2(t-y)$, which is most positive when $t = 2y$ (because $y \ge 0$, by the first constraint). At that point, the right-hand expression in absolute values is
\begin{align}
|2(t-y) - 3(1 + y^2) | 
&= |2(2y-y) - 3(1 + y^2) | \\
&= |2y - 3(1 + y^2) | \\
&= |-3y^2 + 2y - 3|
\end{align}
The discriminant of that quadratic is $4 - 4 \cdot (-3) \cdot (-3) < 0$, so it has no real roots. It's therefore always negative (because it's negative for $y = 0$), so we can safely negate it and remove the absolute value signs. Hence the new problem is to find the smallest $a$ with the property that, for

$$
0 \le y \\
0 < t < 2y,
$$
we have 
\begin{align}
2(2y - t) &\le a (3y^2 + 3 -  2(t - y)) \\
4y - 2t &\le a (3y^2 + 3 -  2t + 2y) \\
4y - 2t &\le 3ay^2 + 3a -  2at + 2ay \\
4y  &\le 3ay^2 + 3a -  2(a-1)t + 2ay \\
0  &\le 3ay^2 + 3a -  2(a-1)t + 2(a-2)y \\
0  &\le (3a)y^2 + 2(a-2)y + [3a -  2(a-1)t] \\
\end{align}

Notice that this inequality can only possibly hold for all $y$, even fixing $t = 0$, if $a \ge 0$, so we'll only consider that case from now on.

Now a quadratic of the form $At^2 + Bt + C$, with $A > 0$, takes on its minimum at $t = -\frac{B}{2A}$, and the value there is 
$$
\frac{4AC - B^2}{4A}.
$$
Applying this to our polynomial, the min occurs at 
$$
y_0 = -\frac{-2(a-2)}{6a} = \frac{2-a}{3a},
$$
with value 
$$
\frac{4 ( 3a) (3a -  2(a-1)t) - (2(a-2))^2}{6a}
$$
or, in the event that $y_0$ is a negative number (i.e., $ -2 < a < 2$), at $y = 0$, where the value is 
$$
3a -  2(a-1)t.
$$

In this second case, we need only look at $0 \le a < 2$< since we already established that negative values of $a$ were impossible.

... and that's where I'm going to leave it. I may have made some algebra error along the way, but at least I've reduceds things to a state where it's a matter of algebra and ordinary calculus, and I hope you can carry out the remaining steps.

Comment: Thank you dear, and I am sorry that I forgot to mentioned the condition $|~x~|<y$

Comment: See additional work in answer.